# Need to compare date object without seconds

Tags: java

I take two date time object in database. And I need to compare it without seconds.

Date 1 Value :  2018-05-25T13:55:24.000+05:30
Date 2 value :  2018-05-31T08:31:00.000+05:30

I need to check date 1 is after date 2.

```
if(Checks.checkNotNull(dateTime) && (partiallyInvalidateDate.isAfter(dateTime))){
    code = null;
  }
```

but I need to do above comparison without second part. Need some expert help to do it.

Comment: Use a `LocalDateTime` and use `dateTime.withSeconds(0).withNano(0)` to zero out those values. You could also use `trunctaedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` if that were easier

Comment: what is the datebase you use

Comment: @AnushkaEkanayake sql server 2017.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're getting date times from `java.sql.ResultSet` as `java.sql.Timestamp`, you can set the seconds and nanos directly on those objects then compare with `after` (though you'll get a deprecated warning on `setSeconds`). Test with mock Timestamps:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class TestTimestamp {

     public static void main(String []args){
        Timestamp ts1 = Timestamp.valueOf("2011-12-25 11:12:13");
        Timestamp ts2 = Timestamp.valueOf("2011-12-25 11:12:14");

        ts1.setSeconds(0);
        ts1.setNanos(0);
        ts2.setSeconds(0);
        ts2.setNanos(0);

        System.out.println(ts1);
        System.out.println(ts2);
        //should print false since they're now identical
        System.out.println(ts2.after(ts1));
    }
}
```

If you need to use LocalDateTime, do this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Test{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Timestamp ts1 = Timestamp.valueOf("2011-12-25 11:12:13");
        Timestamp ts2 = Timestamp.valueOf("2011-12-25 11:12:14");

        LocalDateTime dt1 = ts1.toLocalDateTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        LocalDateTime dt2 = ts2.toLocalDateTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

        System.out.println(dt1);
        System.out.println(dt2);
        //should print false since they're now identical
        System.out.println(dt2.isAfter(dt1));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I consider [MadProgrammer’s suggestion to use `truncatedTo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616673/need-to-compare-date-object-without-seconds#comment88243163_50616673) best:

```
    OffsetDateTime date1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-05-25T13:55:24.000+05:30");
    OffsetDateTime date2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-05-31T08:31:00.000+05:30");

    if (date1.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES).isAfter(date2.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES))) {
        System.out.println("Is after ignoring seconds and smaller");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Is on or before ignoring seconds and smaller");
    }
```

Output in this case:

> Is on or before ignoring seconds and smaller

`truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` sets seconds and smaller units (down to nanoseconds) to 0. As the date-time is immutable, a modified copy is returned. From [the docs of the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-):

> Truncation returns a copy of the original date-time with fields
>   smaller than the specified unit set to zero. For example, truncating
>   with the minutes unit will set the second-of-minute and nano-of-second
>   field to zero.

If you are using `ZonedDateTime`, no problem, it too has a `truncatedTo` method with the same effect, as have even more of the classes of `java.time`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so native than working with `DateFormat` or smth. like that, but this is the most simple way how to do this:

```
public static int compareUpToMinutes(long d1, long d2) {
    return Long.compare(d1 / 10000, d2 / 10000);
}
```

***Examples:***

```
final ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
final Function<ZonedDateTime, Long> milli = d -> d.withSecond(10).toInstant().toEpochMilli();

compareUpToMinutes(milli.apply(date.withSecond(10)), milli.apply(date.withSecond(11))); //  0 => d1 = d2
compareUpToMinutes(milli.apply(date.withMinute(10)), milli.apply(date.withMinute(11))); // -1 => d1 < d2
compareUpToMinutes(milli.apply(date.withMinute(22)), milli.apply(date.withMinute(21))); //  1 => d1 > d2
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer followings, hope you can get a solution with them.

SQL-Server 2008 and later:
CAST(timestamp AS DATE)

SQL-Server 2005 and Earlier
 DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, timestamp), 0)

SQLite
 DATE(timestamp)

Oracle
 TRUNC(timestamp)

MySQL
DATE(timestamp)